# $F$ is incompressible $\iff$ $G$ is incompressible

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If $F, G$ are vector fields, and $F(G(x,y)), G(F(x,y)):  \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ are the identity $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y)$, prove that F is incompressible $\iff$ G is incompressible.

I know you have to suppose F incompressible to get G incompressible and vice versa, but I'm having some trouble. I'm not sure how the composite functions link in with the functions F and G. I can see F(G(x,y)),G(F(x,y)) have divergence 2 also. Just not sure how to tackle it. Hints would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome. People have a tendency to downvote if you do not share e.g. in which context you have seen this problem, what have you tried, and where you are stuck at.

Comment: Thanks. I see - I didn't realise. I know you have to suppose F incompressible to get G incompressible and vice versa, but I'm having some trouble. I'm not sure how the composite functions link in with the functions F and G. I can see $F(G(x,y)), G(F(x,y))$ have divergence 2 also. Just not sure how to tackle it. Hints would be welcome.

Comment: @Jonathon If you [edit] that comment into your question, I'm pretty sure it won't get further downvotes.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions.

Comment: Do you know the [multivariable chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that the divergence of $F$ is zero iff the divergence of $G$ is zero. Denote the two components of $F=(u,v)$. Since you asked for hints, I will give two hints and not elaborate the details.

(1) Try the simplest case first, where $F$ is a linear vector field $F(x,y) = (ax+by,cx+dy)$. The divergence is $a+d$. If you know about matrices then you know that the inverse $G(u,v) = (du-bv,-cu+av)$ divided by the determinant, so the divergence of $G$ is a multiple of the divergence of $F$.

(2) To use the multivariable chain rule, write the derivative of the composition
$G\circ F=$ identity as the matrix product $DG\,DF = I$. Use that to relate the divergence of $F$ to that of $G$. (It is true that the
divergence of the identity function $(x,y)$ is 2 but that doesn't help.)